# Using Foundation 5 off-canvas-menu with Wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I am trying to integrate Zurb Foundation 5 into a Wordpress theme. I can get it working fine but I'm puzzled by a seeming issue which make it unworkable in Wordpress.

Please see this code for making the off-canvas menu work, and following the code I outline my question:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">    

        <nav class="tab-bar">
            <section class="left-small">
                <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
            </section>
            <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
                <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="right-small">
                <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
            </section>
        </nav>

        <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
            <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>

        <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
            <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label>Users</label></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>

        <section class="main-section">
            <!-- MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE -->
        </section>

        <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that all of the page content must be wrapped inside that  element near the end - **which is all wrapped up inside the "off-canvas-wrap"**.

If this is so, how does the modular nature of wordpress code work? The entire page would need to be in the header.php, with no modularity.

I feel I must be missing something.

Really hope someone can help.

Best wishes, Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the example on [Zurb's docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html), I get the impression that you would take this code and break it up into smaller templates like how the _s theme does it.

Starting in your header.php

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
<div class="inner-wrap">
```

Then using [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) for example a template named tab-bar could be:

```
<nav class="tab-bar">
        <section class="left-small">
            <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
        </section>
        <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
            <h1 class="title">Foundation</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="right-small">
            <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
        </section>
    </nav>
```

Then another template named left-off-canvas could call:

```
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

And yet another template could call the right off canvas.

```
    <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li><label>Users</label></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hari Seldon</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

Next in your index.php file you can then call the loop with your main content

```
<section class="main-section">
   <!-- MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE -->
</section>
```

Then close it all off in your footer.php

```
 <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

 </div>
</div>
```

Using templates this way can really break up and keep the modularity your looking for.

Comment: Thank you @butchpage I'll give that a go this week and report back.